# the print function deos not work in python

Tags: python

I have been trying to find some keywords listed a file in another file, if the keyword is found, then print the keyword. Here is my code, python does not generate any errors but I do not see anything printed either. (I am pretty sure that keywords are existed in the file that I used the find function on)

```
keyword_array = []
with open('localDrive\\C0577785-MeshID.txt') as my_keywordfile:    
        for keyword in my_keywordfile.readlines():
            keyword_array.append(keyword.lower())
            # print(keyword)

with open('localdrive\\file') as my_dataset:
    for line in my_dataset.readlines():
        for keywords in keyword_array:        
            if line.lower().find(keywords) >= 0:                
                print("keywords:", keywords,"\n")
                break
```

Am I missing anything?
Thanks

Comment: The lines read from your keyword file include the trailing newline character; they therefore won't be found in your data file unless the keyword was the very last thing on a line.  Build the keyword list with `keyword_array.append(keyword.strip().lower())`

Comment: @jasonharper, you solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read a line from a file, it typically has a newline character at the end of the line...

- '\n' (Linux) or
- '\r\n' (Windows)

So before you append your lines to the list, you should strip any newline characters using the `strip()` function.

Hope that can help you

Answer (score 0):

The credit goes to @jasonharper.
The lines read from your keyword file include the trailing newline character; they therefore won't be found in your data file unless the keyword was the very last thing on a line. Build the keyword list with keyword_array.append(keyword.strip().lower())"